# Differentiating $f(x):=\int_a^x g(t,x)\,\mathrm dt$

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Suppose that $g\in C^1(\Bbb R^2,\Bbb R)$. Then I want to differentiate the function defined by

$$f(x):=\int_a^x g(t,x)\,\mathrm dt$$

I want to check if my differentiation is correct. By the fundamental theorem of calculus we can set $f(x)=G(x,x)-G(a,x)$, hence if I didnt a mistake

$$\partial f(x)=g(x,x)-g(a,x)+\partial_2G(x,x)$$

My questions:

1. it is the above correct? (If not, please show me what is the correct answer.)
2. the above can be simplified further, that is, we can rewrite $\partial_2 G(x,x)$ in terms of $g$ or $f$?

Comment: See the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F(x,y) =\int_a^x g(t,y)\,\mathrm dt$$

Then $f(x):=F(x,x)$ and

$$f'(x)= \frac{d}{dx}F(x,x) =[\partial_x F](x,x)+[\partial_y F](x,x) = g(x,x) +\int_a^x \partial_x g(t,x)\,\mathrm dt$$

Given that, $$[\partial_x F](x,y) =g(x,y) ~~~~~\text{and}~~~~[\partial_yF](x,y) =\int_a^x \partial_x g(t,y)\,\mathrm dt$$

and

Comment: thanks, I saw my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can define $F(x,y) = \int_a^x g(t,y)\,dt$. It is $F(x,x) = f(x)$.
Now it is
$$ \frac d{dx} f(x) = \frac d{dx} = \partial_1 F(x,x) + \partial_2 F(x,x)
= g(x,x) + \int_a^x\partial_xg(t,x)\,dt $$
assuming that integral and derivative commute. (Which for "nice" functions $g$ is the case.)

---

You can see this by seeing $(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$ as a vector. Then we can use the chain rule:
\begin{align}
\frac d{ds}F(s,s) &= F'(s,s)\cdot\frac d{ds}\begin{bmatrix}s\\s\end{bmatrix}\\
& = [\partial_1 F(s,s), \partial_2 F(s,s)]\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \partial_1 F(s,s) + \partial_2 F(s,s).
\end{align}